# Java program cannot find number of columns in a file

Tags: java, arrays

So, I have a 2D array from a file and i am trying to find the number of rows and columns from the file. I succeeded in finding the number of rows, but for columns im not able to. My data is separated by tabs in the file

```
array.txt

4   5   1   9   0
3   4   5   0   5
2   7   7   4   5
```

---

```
public class readFile
    {
    private static Scanner infile;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Opening file for reading data
        try
        {
            infile = new Scanner(new 


       File("C:\\Users\\array.txt"));
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Creating File");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //COUNTING THE NUMBER OF ROWS AND COLUMNS IN FILE
        int rows = 0;
        while(infile.hasNextLine())
        {
            rows++;
            infile.nextLine();
        }

        int columns = 0;
        if (infile.hasNextLine())
        {
            columns = infile.nextLine().split("\t").length;
        }


        System.out.println(rows);
        System.out.println(columns);


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops until the end of the file:

```
 while(infile.hasNextLine())
 {
     rows++;
     infile.nextLine();
 }
```

So your consequent call to `if (infile.hasNextLine())` always returns false.

You should either recreate your scanner and start reading the file anew, or start with calculating the columns for the first line and then count the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current output of this when you run your code?

```
        columns = infile.nextLine().split("\t").length;
```

is it 0? or 4? If 4, then you always just have add 1 I guess since there are only 4 number of tabs each row....also, it would be brittle to use spaces or tabs as delimiter, I would recommend comma instead.

If the output is 0, that could mean that the tab characters in your text file is not represented as tab in the code and not equal to "\t"